# error: ‘bag’ does not name a type

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have added rosbag dependencies in cmakefile.txt and package.xml and included essential ros headers but still catkin_make shows errors ( this not name a type that not name a type). Please help i really dont understand whats going wrong.

```
i have copied file from this ros tutorial : (http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)
```

**Make Error :**

```
 error: ‘bag’ does not name a type
 bag.open("~/bagfiles/2016-12-20-18-18-30.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);
 ^
/home/mandeep/catkin_ws/src/proto1/proto1_moveit/src/rosplay.cpp:11:1: error: ‘topics’ does not name a type
 topics.push_back(std::string("chatter"));
 ^
/home/mandeep/catkin_ws/src/proto1/proto1_moveit/src/rosplay.cpp:12:1: error: ‘topics’ does not name a type
 topics.push_back(std::string("numbers"));
 ^
/home/mandeep/catkin_ws/src/proto1/proto1_moveit/src/rosplay.cpp:16:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
 foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
  ^
/home/mandeep/catkin_ws/src/proto1/proto1_moveit/src/rosplay.cpp:16:44: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
                                            ^
/home/mandeep/catkin_ws/src/proto1/proto1_moveit/src/rosplay.cpp:16:897: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
```

**rosplay.cpp**

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

rosbag::Bag bag;
bag.open("~/bagfiles/2016-12-20-18-18-30.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);

std::vector<std::string> topics;
topics.push_back(std::string("chatter"));
topics.push_back(std::string("numbers"));

rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    std_msgs::String::ConstPtr s = m.instantiate<std_msgs::String>();
    if (s != NULL)
        ASSERT_EQ(s->data, std::string("foo"));

    std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Int32>();
    if (i != NULL)
        ASSERT_EQ(i->data, 42);
}

bag.close();
```

**There goes my Cmakefiles.txt : Highlighted part added for rosplay.cpp**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(proto1_moveit)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake-modules)  ####CHANGE
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)  ####CHANGE
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)  ####CHANGE

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             moveit_core
             moveit_ros_planning
             moveit_ros_planning_interface
             pluginlib
             rosbag
             cmake_modules
             geometric_shapes
             joint_trajectory_controller
             joint_trajectory_action
             moveit_simple_controller_manager
             industrial_robot_simulator
             actionlib
             actionlib_msgs
             control_msgs
             trajectory_msgs
             moveit_msgs
             shape_msgs
             chef_arm_kinematics
)

find_package(MySqlClient REQUIRED) ###CHANGE

find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem date_time thread)

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS}) ###CHANGE

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS 
    include
  LIBRARIES 
    ik_utils_proto
    pick_proto
    place_proto
    dispense_proto
    stir_proto
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    rosbag
    moveit_core
    moveit_ros_planning_interface
    interactive_markers
    std_msgs
    actionlib_msgs
    shape_msgs
    chef_arm_kinematics
)

add_definitions(${MYSQL_DEFINITIONS}) ##CHANGE

add_library(pick_proto src/pick_proto.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(pick_proto ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}) ###CHANGE
install(TARGETS pick_proto
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
add_library(place_proto src/place_proto.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(place_proto ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}) ###CHANGE
install(TARGETS place_proto
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
add_library(dispense_proto src/dispense_proto.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(dispense_proto ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}) ###CHANGE
install(TARGETS dispense_proto
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
add_library(stir_proto src/stir_proto.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(stir_proto ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}) ###CHANGE
install(TARGETS stir_proto
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
add_executable(environment_proto src/environment_proto.cpp)
target_link_libraries(environment_proto ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}) ###CHANGE
install(TARGETS environment_proto DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

**add_executable(rosplay src/rosplay.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosplay ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) 
install(TARGETS rosplay DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})**

install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY config DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

**and there goes my package.xml**

```
<package>

  <name>proto1_moveit</name>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
  <description>
     An automatically generated package with all the configuration and launch files for using the description with the MoveIt Motion Planning Framework
  </description>
  <author email="assistant@moveit.ros.org">MoveIt Setup Assistant</author>
  <maintainer email="assistant@moveit.ros.org">MoveIt Setup Assistant</maintainer>

  <license>BSD</license>

  <url type="website">http://moveit.ros.org/</url>
  <url type="bugtracker">https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_setup_assistant/issues</url>
  <url type="repository">https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_setup_assistant</url>

  <run_depend>moveit_core</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_ros_planning</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pluginlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cmake_modules</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometric_shapes</run_depend>
  <run_depend>interactive_markers</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_ros_move_group</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_planners_ompl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_ros_visualization</run_depend>
  <run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>robot_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>xacro</run_depend>
  <run_depend>moveit_simple_controller_manager</run_depend>
  <run_depend>joint_trajectory_controller</run_depend>
  <run_depend>industrial_robot_simulator</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>trajectory_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>control_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>joint_trajectory_action</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>shape_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>chef_arm_kinematics</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosbag</run_depend>

  <build_depend>shape_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_ros_perception</build_depend>
  <build_depend>interactive_markers</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometric_shapes</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_simple_controller_manager</build_depend>
  <build_depend>joint_trajectory_controller</build_depend>
  <build_depend>bot_arm</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>trajectory_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>control_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>joint_trajectory_action</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>chef_arm_kinematics</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
    <export>
    <cpp lflags="-lmysqlclient"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250447/error:-%E2%80%98bag%E2%80%99-does-not-name-a-type/) by [Mandeep Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28858/mandeep-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
Please include your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` and an example of the kind of errors you are getting.

We cannot help you without the proper information.

**Comment by [Mandeep Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28858/mandeep-singh/) on 2016-12-21**:
I have added more info please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem :
the cpp file given on ros tutorial is not ready for direct usage (f).
We need to include it in int main()
and include a few more libraries like
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
and
remove ASSERT_EQ as it will further give error.

rosplay.cpp

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "bag_it");
    rosbag::Bag bag;
    bag.open("~/bagfiles/2016-12-20-18-18-30.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);

    std::vector<std::string> topics;
    topics.push_back(std::string("chatter"));
    topics.push_back(std::string("numbers"));

    rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

    foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
    {
        std_msgs::String::ConstPtr s = m.instantiate<std_msgs::String>();
        if (s != NULL)
            std::cout << s->data << std::endl;

        std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Int32>();
        if (i != NULL)
            std::cout << i->data << std::endl;
    }

    bag.close();
    return (0);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Mandeep Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28858/mandeep-singh/) with karma: 36 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2